# The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception for Win8 64bit, VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, runtime-error, emgucv

I am trying to use EmguCV to make a website in Visual Studio. Getting an error `The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception` with the Inner Exception `An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B).`

Following are the details of my setup:

> Windows 8 64-bit
>
> VS2012
>
> Emgu library 2.3 for Windows x64

Most of the help I saw in forums was for a project, but in case it matters, this is a website.

I have already copied all DLLs into '`Website\bin`' folder. So, I doubt if that is the problem. I put these DLLs into `System32` and `SysWOW64` folders as well. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, this error occurs when you forgot to copy or include the opencv dlls or there's an error in your MSVCRT installation. You may see additional info at [Emgu Wiki](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.).