# CV.Invoke on emgu

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I keep getting a cv.invoke when I try to read a simpe image. My application has no further code than this (emgu-opencv wise). I checked the call stack and it says `Thrown: "Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core249': The specified module could not be found.`

The problem is that I tried adding the two .dlls `(opencv_core249 and opencv_imgproc249)` in the solution as resource (with copy always in properties) and still get the exception
also tried changing their property as content and still nothing.

Also tried manually copying them in the debug folder and still I get the same exception.
I have already followed the guidelines point out at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426942/the-type-initializer-for-emgu-cv-cvinvoke-threw-an-exception-for-win8-64bit-v/14662701#14662701) but still I get the same error

If it is of any help I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Windows 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution to your problem can also be addressed as pointed out in this thread:

[The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception for Win8 64bit, VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426942/the-type-initializer-for-emgu-cv-cvinvoke-threw-an-exception-for-win8-64bit-v/14662701#14662701)

There's a link there pointing to emgucv forum.

In addition, it pays to check if you are using the correct platform target for the project you are trying to build (e.g., x86 and 64 bit).

Comment: I have already done what the other question says. It does not work

Answer (score 3):

Depending of the platforms settings of your solution....

If you are building your solution on "x64" xor "x86" you must copy those dlls inside your debug folder

..But if you are building for "Any Cpu" you will need to create, inside your debug folder, both "x86" and "x64" Folders. And inside of them the related libraries you need. Cause, your solution will requere both, depending the cpu...

Comment: My problem was already fixed, but I upvote you for your effort

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your target platform (x64 or x86) is set under the configuration options and make sure that all the opencv libraries are in the same directory as your executing directory.

If this does not work, try running any emgu example, do they work?