# Visual studio 2012 and EmguCV Issue

Tags: c#, opencv, visual-studio-2012, emgucv

I got this error when i try next:

```
var openCVImg = new Image<Bgr, byte>(colorBitmap.ToBitmap());
```

Error details:

```
{"Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core249': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"}
```

I add to my Path directory in system to check form dlls on ~\Emgu\emgucv-windows-universal-gpu 2.4.9.1847\lib

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have probably forgotten to copy or include the opencv dlls or there's an error in your MSVCRT installation. 
Check out [The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception for Win8 64bit, VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426942/the-type-initializer-for-emgu-cv-cvinvoke-threw-an-exception-for-win8-64bit-v/14662701#14662701) and http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation#The_type_initializer_for_.27Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.27_threw_an_exception.

Comment: Thanks this worked, i copied opencv libraries directly to my project bin.